# Can I add resistors?

Tags: arduino, resistors

How can I achieve 10k resistance?

I just got my photocell in the mail, totally forgot the 10k resistor. The thing is I have a lot of different resistors in the span 1, 10, 27, 37,56, 68, 82, 100.

Is there a way I can put them in parallel/series and make a 10k? Or do I need a 10k? How does it work?

Comment: It isn't feasible with those values.

Comment: Resistors in series just add up. So you could use 100 resistors of 100 ohms in series if you have enough patience to assemble it and enough resistors to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add resistors in series to obtain the sum of their resistances. However, from the list provided, unless you missed the "k" on some of them, it will be quite a lot of resistors in series to achieve 10k Ohms of resistance.

Comment: what i figured :-/ I've just started fiddling around with microcontrollers. great fun, but needs planning tho. my fault

Comment: One purchase you will not regret is a full set of assorted resistors, all ranges from the E (Ohms) through the M (MegaOhms). Other must-haves: a multimeter, even an el cheapo if necessary, and a bunch of LEDs. The rest will suggest itself.

Comment: Got the multimeter, leds and some resistors. Going to buy a kit of those resistors :-/